# Вывод результата

Tags: python

Есть результат:

```
test 1:4  a1, a1_2, a1_3, a2, a2_2
```

Нужно найти во втором столбец:

```
a1      3
a1_2    4
a1_3    5
a2      5
a2_2    7
```

И получить:

```
test 1:4  3,4,5,5,7
```

Comment: Что уже сделано, какие мысли?

Comment: вот именно не каких) В голову ничего не приходит. Есть одна в первом скрипте собрать словарь новый. типа
test 1:4 a1
test 1:4 a1_2 

и дальше обрабатывать

Comment: Второй преобразовать в словарь, а затем преобразовать первый

Comment: Ваши столбцы, это что за структуры Python - списки? Или просто стринги?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может так?

```
import re
firstline = re.split(r'\s*[, ]\s*', input())
d = {}
try:
  while True: 
    [l1, l2] = input().split()
    d[l1] = l2
except EOFError: 
  f = []
  for i in firstline[2:] :
    f.append(d[i])
  firstline = firstline[:2]
  firstline.append(','.join(f))
  print(' '.join(firstline))
```

**UPD** Исправлено регулярное выражение `r'\s*,?\s*'` на `r'\s*[, ]\s*'`. Нервирует то, что первоначальному выражению удовлетворяет пустая строка.

Comment: Я переписал свой скрипт и все получилось, лень было переписывать, хотел вывод из двух скриптов скрестить)

Comment: Всем спасибо!